# How to make an element shake every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html with the following structure:

```
<li><a class="" href="?sort-by=popular">Barang Terpopuler</a></li>
```

How do I make this element shake (move left and right) every 5 seconds using jQuery? Is there a built in animation for this?

Comment: I don't think their is built in function but why not setInterval with jQuery animate.

Comment: You can use the [Shake jQuery UI Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/), along with `setInterval` to get the desired effect!

Comment: Did you update your question to include "move left and right"? I didn't see this first time round. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({
            "position" : "relative"
        });
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            $(this).animate({
                left : -25
            }, 10).animate({
                left : 0
            }, 50).animate({
                left : 25
            }, 10).animate({
                left : 0
            }, 50);
        }
    });
    return this;
}
setInterval(function() {
    $('li').shake();
}, 5000);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JppPG/334/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a plugin, such as [classyWiggle](http://www.class.pm/#projects) which offers a little more functionality than rolling your own (which might or might not be a good thing).

Once you have included the plugin, you give an element the class `wiggle`

```
<img class="wiggle" src="images/image1.jpg" />
```

Then you do:

```
$('.wiggle').wiggle();
```

The plugin has a number of options you can set:

```
degrees - an Array object which outlines the cycle of rotation for a wiggle increment.
delay - allows you to specify, in milliseconds, the delay between switching from one rotation degree to the next (see degrees). A higher number creates a slower "wiggle."
limit - allows you to specify the maximum number of wiggles.
randomStart - a boolean value which tells the plugin to start wiggling all matched elements at the same degree or a random one.
onWiggle - an event that is fired off with the end of each wiggle.
onWiggleStart - an event that is fired off when the wiggling effect first starts.
onWiggleStop - an event that is fired off when the wiggling effect is stopped.
```

As well as three methods you can call:

```
start() - starts the wiggle effect.
stop() - stops the wiggle effect.
isWiggling() - a method that can be used to determine if the matched element is currently "wiggling."
```

You might have it repeat every five seconds like so:

```
function wiggleForOneSecond(el){
    el.wiggle();
    setTimeout(function(){el.wiggle('stop')},1000)
}

setInterval(function(){wiggleForOneSecond($('.wiggle'))},5000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/b8rU6/)

Answer (score 1):

...an example using pure JS (not JQ);

html:

```
<li><a class="shakeit" href="?sort-by=popular">Barang Terpopuler</a></li>
```

JS:

```
var interval;
shakeit = function(element){
    element.style.display = "block";
    var x = -1;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(x == -1){
            element.style.marginLeft = "5px";
        }else{
            switch(x){
                case 0 :
                    element.style.marginLeft = "-5px";
                break;
                case 1 :
                    element.style.marginLeft = "0px";
                    element.style.marginTop = "5px";
                break;
                case 2 :
                    element.style.marginTop = "-5px";
                break;
                default :
                    element.style.marginTop = "0px";
                    clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        x++;
    },50)    
}

shakeit(document.getElementsByClassName("shakeit")[0]);
setInterval(function(){
    shakeit(document.getElementsByClassName("shakeit")[0]);
},5000);
```

fiddler example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnx3a/1/

integrated with JQ:

```
$.fn.shakeit = function(obj){
    var interval;
    set = $.extend({
        time : 5000, //interval
        top : "3px", 
        bottom : "3px",
        left : "3px",
        right : "3px"
    }, obj);

    var shake = function(element){
        element.style.display = "block";
        var x = -1;
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(x == -1){
                element.style.marginLeft = set.right;
            }else{
                switch(x){
                    case 0 :
                        element.style.marginLeft = "-"+set.left;
                    break;
                    case 1 :
                        element.style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        element.style.marginTop = set.top;
                    break;
                    case 2 :
                        element.style.marginTop = "-"+set.bottom;
                    break;
                    default :
                        element.style.marginTop = "0px";
                        clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
            x++;
        },50);
    }

    return $(this).each(function(i,el){            
            shake(el);
            setInterval(function(){
                shake(el);
            },set.time);
        });
}
$(".shakeit").shakeit();
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fnx3a/2/

:) enjoy